# Flutter and Firebase Authentication problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

Flutter fellow today I have a problem with the Firebase Authentication service.
Well then let me explain the situation. I have a page that let you select a type of user, if you select "Guest" you will push through the app's dashboard page `Nav()` without sign-in but if select "Sign-in" app will push you to the login page `Login()`.

```
class SelectUser extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectUser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF20348F),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.amber,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
              ),
              child: TextButton(
                child: const Text('Guest'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => const Nav(),
                    ),
                    (route) => false,
                  );
                },
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: const Color(0xFF20348F),
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.amber,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
              ),
              child: TextButton(
                child: const Text('Sign-In'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (contex) {
                    return const Login();
                  }));
                },
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: const Color(0xFF20348F),
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In `Nav()` I use *BottomNavigationBarItem* and have a several widget included `Proflie()`
inside.
I already test the sign-up, sign-out and registration function everything is perfectly fine but when I try to be tricky in `Proflie()` and I face...let's said the weird problem. First let's me show you the code in the `Proflie()`.

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const Profile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  String? _email;
  DateTime? _creationTime;
  DateTime? _lastSignIn;
  bool? _status;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userStatus();
    return userForm();
  }

  userStatus() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((event) {
      if (event == null) {
        _status = false;
      } else {
        _status = true;
        _email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;
        _creationTime =
            FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.metadata.creationTime;
        _lastSignIn =
            FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.metadata.lastSignInTime;
      }
    });
  }

  Widget userForm() {
    if (_status == true) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: defaultAppBar('Profile'),
        body: Center(
          child: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Text(
                  'Email: $_email',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Text(
                  'Creation Time: $_creationTime',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Text(
                  'Last Sign-In: $_lastSignIn',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 45),
              button('Change password', 1),
              const SizedBox(height: 18),
              button('Change email', 2),
              const SizedBox(height: 18),
              button('Sign-out', 0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Center(
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 100),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
              child: const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Please sign-in to use this Feature',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            button('Login', 3),
            const SizedBox(height: 18),
            button('Register', 4),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget button(String txt, int _nav) {
    Color? _color = const Color(0xFF20348F);
    if (_nav == 0) {
      _color = Colors.red;
    }
    return TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: _color,
        textStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(txt),
      onPressed: () {
        if (_nav == 0) {
          FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => const SelectUser(),
            ),
            (route) => false,
          );
        } else {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (contex) {
            if (_nav == 1) {
              return const EditPass();
            } else if (_nav == 2) {
              return const EditEmail();
            } else if (_nav == 3) {
              return const Login();
            } else {
              return const Register();
            }
          }));
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to use `userStatus()` to identify the "User" and "Guest" and that function I use *FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((event)* to check user state in Firebase Authentication(Not really sure am I doing the right way if not please teach me how to check user state) if `event == null` that mean no user sign-in right now. I'm just going to set `_status = false` so the "Guest" should found the `else` case in `userForm()`. Otherwise `_status = true` this mean user is signed-in and `userForm()` should go to `if (_status == true)` case.

**Now the problem is when I success to sign-in on the `Login()`. In `Profile()` I ended up got the `else` case of  `userForm()` instead but that not all! When I hot reloaded the IDE it turn out now I'm in the `if (_status == true)` case.** Yeah like said it a weird problem the first time that app loaded the page it go to false case but when hot reloaded it turn to true case. I'm not so sure the error is from `Profile()` or `Login()`. I'm just going leave the `Login()` then.

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var _email = "";
  var _password = "";

  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  bool _passwordVisible = true;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return formLogin();
  }

  Widget formLogin() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: defaultAppBar('Sign-In'),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                buildEmail(),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
                buildPassword('Password', 'Your password...'),
                const SizedBox(height: 50),
                button('Sign-in', 0),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
                button('Sign-up', 1),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  userLogin() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => const Nav(),
        ),
        (route) => false,
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
            content: Text(
              "Email not found",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
            content: Text(
              "Password incorrect",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  TextButton button(String txt, int nav) {
    return TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: const Color(0xFF20348F),
        textStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(txt),
      onPressed: () {
        if (nav == 0) {
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            setState(() {
              _email = emailController.text;
              _password = passwordController.text;
            });
            userLogin();
          }
        } else {
          _formKey.currentState!.reset();
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (contex) {
            return const Register();
          }));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildEmail() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Email',
        hintText: 'name@example.com',
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 15),
      ),
      controller: emailController,
      validator: MultiValidator([
        RequiredValidator(errorText: "Email is required"),
        EmailValidator(errorText: "The format of email is incorrect")
      ]),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
    );
  }

  Widget buildPassword(String _txt1, String _txt2) {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: _passwordVisible,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: _txt1,
        hintText: _txt2,
        suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _passwordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
          ),
        ),
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.vpn_key_outlined),
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        errorStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 15),
      ),
      controller: passwordController,
      validator: RequiredValidator(errorText: "Password is required"),
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
    );
  }
}
```

If you guy could help me I'd gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a .gist i would be of help to u, also in your profile page i can see issue's that u r listening to the user changes in the build, its very unpractical to add it in the build because flutter will call the build method multiple times , build should be clean, also potential memory leaks are there since u r not disposing the streams.